# How to change my endpoint in app.config file

Tags: c#, rest, soap

I am trying to change the endpoint dynamically in my form:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModelSectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

ClientSection clientSection = serviceModelSectionGroup.Client;

var el = clientSection.Endpoints[0];
var newurl = el.Adress(new Uri("http://localhost:9000/MyService");
```